# Searchable spinner stopped working after update to Giraffe

Tags: android, spinner, searchable

I have been using toptoche searchable spinner library sucessfully for a few years now, recent updates to Android Studio seem to have broken it. I have made no changes to the app, aside from updating the compilesdk requirements. I get this error message when I try to app a searchable spinner library:

```
Class referenced in the layout file, com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner, was not found in the project or the libraries
```

I get the same message when I try to and any of the other searchable spinner libraries available. Am I missing something?
This happened after updating to Giraffe and the push to go Kotlin, which I'm avoiding because I'm not a pro programmer just a hobbyist that makes app for myself at work.